# My class compiles but will not run correctly! (BlueJ)

Tags: java, compilation

Okay so I will put in my code below this but let me explain. I am trying to find the value of vals[2][1]. But when I type in my code, it compiles, I hit void main(String[] args), but then nothing happens. It does not say error, it does not pop up a window. Why?

```
public class New
{
    public static void main(String[] args){

       double[][] vals = {{1.1, 1.3, 1.5},
                                 {3.1, 3.3, 3.5},
                                 {5.1, 5.3, 5.5},
                                 {7.1, 7.3, 7.5}};
                                }
    }
```

Comment: All your code does is assign values to a 2D array. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: You need a JFrame to make stuff pop up in a window.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you actually need to write code to produce output.

For example, to print the value of `vals[2][1]` ...  add this:

```
System.out.println(vals[2][1]);
```